# render :layout => 'application' conflicts with kaminari

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax, kaminari, slim-lang

I am trying to make kaminari ajax button work, but I have one problem which seems to be causing error and stopping from kaminari to work.

index.controller.rb

```
  def index
    @works = Work.page params[:page].per(10)
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.js
    end
    render :layout => 'application'
  end
```

and it returns me with error...

```
undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass
```

Below is what I have in my view file.
root.html.slim

```
= render "layouts/alert"


.mainWrapper.cf
  #workWrapper.cf
    #intro
      h1
        | foriio is a platform for creators.
        br
        | We aim to bring portfolio to all creators.
      p
        | We think, it shouldn’t matter whether you can code or not.
        br
        | Nor whether you know how to use photoshop.
        br
        | So we aim to make things a lot easier for creators to make portfolio.
    #howto
      ul
        li.one-third.column
          = image_tag "step1.png"
          | 1. Sign in with your facebook account
        li.one-third.column
          = image_tag "step2.png"
          | 2. Submit your work, and your portfolio is now ready!
        li.one-third.column
          = image_tag "step3.png"
          | 3. Tag collaborators such as Stylists, Make up artists, etc.
          br
          | Or tag yourself if you were involved!
    h2.recentTitle Recent uploads
    ul#works
      = render :partial => "works"
```

This is the view file for the _works.html.slim

```
- @works.each do | work |
  = link_to work
    li.works
      span.thumb
        = work_image_of work
      h4 = link_to work.title, work, thumb:true
      p.pull-left
        small
          = work.collaborators.count.to_s
          |&nbsp;collaborators
      p.pull-right
        small
          = link_to 'Edit', edit_work_path(work) if can? :update, work
          |&nbsp;
          = link_to 'Destroy', work, data: {:confirm => 'Are you sure?'}, :method => :delete  if can? :delete, work
= paginate @works, remote: true
```

I am guessing those two @works... and render :layout =>application.... can not co-exist??

How could I fix this???
Thank you in advance!

---

note: render :layout => 'application'
loads header and rest of the page.

my trace log

```
Processing by IndexController#root as HTML
  Rendered layouts/_alert.html.slim (0.4ms)
  Rendered index/_works.html.slim (9.9ms)
  Rendered index/root.html.slim (22.9ms)
Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 32ms

NoMethodError - undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass:
  app/views/index/_works.html.slim:1:in `_app_views_index__works_html_slim___3157568365315559456_70136848436740'
  actionview (4.1.5) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
```

Comment: Are you using partials? This doesn't look like a kaminari problem, it looks like if you use: @works in a partial or page rendered by ajax, you need to let the partial know about it. Post the view code please.

Comment: could you prvide the full trace log?

Comment: thx! @МалъСкрылевъ I added the trace log!

Comment: @HirohitoYamada I meant ruby trace log, that can be seen in console/logfile

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ opps,, sorry.. I added that.

Comment: Strange seems @works defaulting to nil, try cases

Comment: @miler350 thx, I added the view code too!

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ Try cases? How should I do that? sorry, I'm not really confident with rails yet...

Comment: with `pry` gem you can just introduce breakpoint to controller before rendering call, and to slim template before access to @works.

Comment: As I suspected: `app/views/index/_works.html.slim:1:in` This means it's not recognizing your instance variable in your partial. I'll propose an answer below that we can work with.

Comment: actually first, try to set explicit variable passing in your controller: `@works = Work.page(params[:page]).per(10)`

Comment: thx, I tried what you said above but I still got the error, --- Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 107ms NoMethodError - undefined method each' for nil:NilClass: app/views/index/_works.html.slim:1:in _app_views_index__works_html_slim__2700991721518835150_70205412240740' @miler350